# Cannot enable WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In an elevated command prompt, I typed:

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

The response is:

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is
unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COME
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCom
   mand

I am running:

Windows 10 Home 64 bit on x64 based processor.

Version 1803

Build 17134.1006

Windows update reports that my system is up to date.
How to proceed?

[EDIT]
If I use the "Turn windows feature on/of" GUI's dialog box, the list of possible features is completely empty.

Comment: Could you try using the GUI approach to install WSL?

Comment: If I do it via the GUI the list of features to choose from is empty (EDIT)

Comment: Empty is quite bad.  [Look here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-windows-features-on-or-off-blank).

Comment: Have you turned on developer mode?

Comment: @HansPassant I have followed the instructions on that page. The dism tool tells me it's missing a file, but it won't tell me which one or how to get it. The log is huge and abacadabra to me.

Comment: @KonstantinBaklaev Yes, developer mode is activated.

Comment: Check the Windows Installer and the Windows Module Installer services. If they are stopped, start them and try opening the Windows components again.